# How to embed instagram carousel videos

Tags: instagram, embed

Instagram single video or image feed can be easily embedded using the embed code. But when I am trying to **embed carousel videos**, it is just showing first media and that too only image. Is there a way to correctly embed such carousel videos.

As an example:
https://www.instagram.com/p/BmOkwXKhbeX/?taken-by=desihoppers

embed code:

```
<blockquote class="instagram-media" data-instgrm-captioned data-instgrm-permalink="https://www.instagram.com/p/BmOkwXKhbeX/?utm_source=ig_embed" data-instgrm-version="9" style=" background:#FFF; border:0; border-radius:3px; box-shadow:0 0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.5),0 1px 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.15); margin: 1px; max-width:540px; min-width:326px; padding:0; width:99.375%; width:-webkit-calc(100% - 2px); width:calc(100% - 2px);"><div style="padding:8px;"> <div style=" background:#F8F8F8; line-height:0; margin-top:40px; padding:50% 0; text-align:center; width:100%;"> <div style=" background:url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAACwAAAAsCAMAAAApWqozAAAABGdBTUEAALGPC/xhBQAAAAFzUkdCAK7OHOkAAAAMUExURczMzPf399fX1+bm5mzY9AMAAADiSURBVDjLvZXbEsMgCES5/P8/t9FuRVCRmU73JWlzosgSIIZURCjo/ad+EQJJB4Hv8BFt+IDpQoCx1wjOSBFhh2XssxEIYn3ulI/6MNReE07UIWJEv8UEOWDS88LY97kqyTliJKKtuYBbruAyVh5wOHiXmpi5we58Ek028czwyuQdLKPG1Bkb4NnM+VeAnfHqn1k4+GPT6uGQcvu2h2OVuIf/gWUFyy8OWEpdyZSa3aVCqpVoVvzZZ2VTnn2wU8qzVjDDetO90GSy9mVLqtgYSy231MxrY6I2gGqjrTY0L8fxCxfCBbhWrsYYAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC); display:block; height:44px; margin:0 auto -44px; position:relative; top:-22px; width:44px;"></div></div> <p style=" margin:8px 0 0 0; padding:0 4px;"> <a href="https://www.instagram.com/p/BmOkwXKhbeX/?utm_source=ig_embed" style=" color:#000; font-family:Arial,sans-serif; font-size:14px; font-style:normal; font-weight:normal; line-height:17px; text-decoration:none; word-wrap:break-word;" target="_blank">So this is what went down at The Duels at @nbcworldofdance It was an honour to share the stage and compete against @opus_dance_collective Watch what @jlo @neyo @derekhough had to say bout us ! Enjoy ! (Swipe Right) #desihoppers #theduels #nbcworldofdanceseason2</a></p> <p style=" color:#c9c8cd; font-family:Arial,sans-serif; font-size:14px; line-height:17px; margin-bottom:0; margin-top:8px; overflow:hidden; padding:8px 0 7px; text-align:center; text-overflow:ellipsis; white-space:nowrap;">A post shared by <a href="https://www.instagram.com/desihoppers/?utm_source=ig_embed" style=" color:#c9c8cd; font-family:Arial,sans-serif; font-size:14px; font-style:normal; font-weight:normal; line-height:17px;" target="_blank"> Official DesiHoppers</a> (@desihoppers) on <time style=" font-family:Arial,sans-serif; font-size:14px; line-height:17px;" datetime="2018-08-08T18:19:46+00:00">Aug 8, 2018 at 11:19am PDT</time></p></div></blockquote> <script async defer src="//www.instagram.com/embed.js"></script>
```

Preview:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was the mistake from instagram side only. It has stopped this feature for two days and after that it starts automatically showing it as carousel.

[image]